# How do I make a reservation with The Fat Duck?

Tags: uk, bookings, restaurants

[Their website](http://www.thefatduck.co.uk/) is mysterious, I believe it is one of the top resturants in the world that every tourist should visit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call the number and make a reservation. If you can't find the number then [here's the information that TripAdvisor has on the venue](http://www.tripadvisor.com/Restaurant_Review-g528798-d1571626-Reviews-The_Fat_Duck-Bray_on_Thames_Berkshire_England.html):

> #### The Fat Duck
>
> High St, Bray, West Berkshire SL6 2AQ, United Kingdom
>
> 00441628580333